# How can I match partial strings / is there a better way?

Tags: python, string, api, dictionary

I am pulling hotel names through the Expedia API and cross referencing results with another  travel service provider.

The problem I am encountering is that many of the hotel names appear differently on the Expedia API than they do with the other provider and I cannot figure out a good way to match them.

I am storing the results of both in separate dicts with room rates. So, for example, the results from Expedia on a search for Vilnius in Lithuania might look like this:

```
expediadict = {'Ramada Hotel & Suites Vilnius': 120, 'Hotel Rinno': 100,
'Vilnius Comfort Hotel': 110}
```

But the results from the other provider might look like this:

```
altproviderdict = {'Ramada Vilnius': 120, 'Rinno Hotel': 100, 
'Comfort Hotel LT': 110}
```

The only thing I can think of doing is stripping out all instances of 'Hotel', 'Vilnius', 'LT' and 'Lithuania' and then testing whether part of the expediadict key matches part of an altprovderdict key. This seems messy and not very Pythonic, so I wondered if any of you had any cleaner ideas?

Comment: Have you heard of regex? Maybe take a look at the `re` module.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian I dont think that is the right solution for this problem at all ...

Comment: Do you have an identifier that is more likely to be universal and unique? Like a phone number, street address, some standardized ID number, etc? You could join on something other than hotel name.

Comment: regex wont help this specific instance. @Robᵩ regrettably I don't have access to an API so I'm scraping. I could do it that way but it would be quite labor intensive (and I've noted that often even the addresses are different!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> def simple_clean(word):
...     return word.lower().replace(" ","").replace("hotel","")
... 
>>> a = "Ramada Hotel & Suites Vilnius"
>>> b = "Hotel Ramada Suites Vilnous"
>>> a = simple_clean(a)
>>> b = simple_clean(b)
>>> a
'ramada&suitesvilnius'
>>> b
'ramadasuitesvilnous'
>>> import difflib
>>> difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,a,b).ratio()
0.9230769230769231
```

1. Do cleaning and normalization of the words : eg. remove words like Hotel,The,Resort etc
   , and convert to lower case without spaces etc
2. Then use a fuzzy string matching algorithm like leveinstein, eg from `difflib` module.

This method is pretty raw and just an example, you can enhance it to suit your needs for optimal results.

Comment: #1 is dangerous. Consider the [Hyatt Place](https://maps.google.com/maps?ie=UTF-8&q=hyatt+place+warrenville&fb=1&gl=us&hq=hyatt+place&hnear=0x880ef8b33c3a5cdb:0xf076cf9f9f29e7f2,Warrenville,+IL&cid=0,0,2122067439554454056&ei=GQw6UofLHZSqyQHQnYHQDw&ved=0CGwQrwswBA) and the Hyatt House in Warrenville, IL. Their names differ only in potentially insignificant words "Place" and "House".

Comment: in which case they would both receive the same match score and both would be returned to the user? which seems like pretty ok behaviour (assuming he is returning some kind of sorted list as opposed to a single entry)

Comment: @rob , Agreed, but that depends on the use case, and user may chose not to remove those words.

Comment: Thanks guys, I had no idea about fuzzy string matching, this will work perfectly. There are some dangers, but the way I'm returning results will limit those risks to an acceptable level. This is exactly why I love SO...

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match names when the words appear in the same order, you might want to use some longest common sub sequence algorithm like it's used in diff tools. But with words instead of characters or lines.

If order is not important, it's simpler: Put all the words of the name into a set like this:

```
set(name.split())
```

and in order to match two names, test the size of the `intersection` of these two sets. Or test if the `symmetric_difference` only contains unimportant words.